# Modelling relation between two similar classes in UML

Tags: uml, associations, aggregation, class-diagram, generalization

I am modeling my project, which I will subsequently implement in Java, using UML. My project involves managing a gym. More specifically, I am currently modeling a class diagram that allows me to organize workout routines (see classes in yellow):

[image]

I have interpreted workout routines as a list of lists: a workout routine is a list of 'WorkoutDay' classes (from 1 to 7), which in turn are a list of 'ExercisesForTheWorkoutRoutine' classes. However, the 'ExercisesForTheWorkoutRoutine' in the workoutRoutines differ from the 'Exercise' class (which only have a name of type String, and a status of type enumeration) because they additionally have a recovery time, a number of repetitions, and a number of sets.

My doubt is about how to connect the two classes 'ExercisesForTheWorkoutRoutine' and 'Exercise'. Because I need that when an exercise is removed from the 'exercises' list (for example, the gym no longer has a certain piece of equipment), all instances of 'exercisesForTheWorkoutRoutine' with the same name as the removed exercise are also eliminated.

I don't know if it's a generalization, a simple association (in this case, I think of a cardinality of 1..1), or an aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, [prefer composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).  "Composition" in this popular advice refers to  OOP *[object composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition)*, that is in UML expressed as an association, a shared aggregation or a composite aggregation.

Indeed the `Exercise` seems to be a kind of template or reference that might very well have other attributes (e.g. status) and completely different behaviors than `ExerciseForWorkout`. You could for example imagine that `Exercise` could later be enriched with links to videos or be associated to an author for digital right management whereas these informations might not be relevant in the `ExerciseForWorkout`. So the generalisation would not be suitable.

You should consider inheritance only if an `ExerciseForWorkout` object could always replace an `Exercise` object. And this does not seem to be the case here.

Nevertheless from a modeling perspective you could wonder if the `ExerciseForWorkout` is always related to an `Exercise`, which your 1..1 multiplicity (in UML this is not called "cardinality") suggests. In this case you should ask yourself if it really needs to duplicate the name of the reference
exercise. Two other alternatives would be 1) to use composition, since the deletion of the `Exercise` (composite) would cause delation of the `ExerciseForWorkout`; 2) to consider `ExerciseForWorkout` as an [association class](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/model_domains/associationclass.html) between `Exercise` and `WorkoutDay`.

Some unrelated remarks:

- multiplicity should be at each end of an association (and 1..1 should be on the Ercise side whereas a * should be on the ExerciseForWorkout side, as I's expext the same reference exercise to be reused multiple times)
- avoid using shared aggregation (white diamond) because while diamonds are forever,  this one has no value since the UML specs do not give any additional semantic compared to a simple association.

Comment: Thank you very much, you've been very clear. Just one thing: the composition is usually used to allow control over the lifecycle of the composing object. Please stop me immediately if you see that perhaps I am already focusing too much on the code rather than on the modeling. However, if I am not mistaken, in my case, the issue is that ExerciseForWorkout would be the composing object, so it would appear that an Exercise is composed of ExerciseForWorkout, which possesses attributes that an Exercise should not have (ex: Sets, Rest and Repetitions).

Comment: @LucaMartorelli Thank you for the opportunity to clarify.  First, a remark to avoid misundertandings:  "composition" is an ambiguous word.  In an OOP context, it generally refers to "object composition" ("composition over inheritance" = use a property of a type instead of inheriting it) and whether or not it means controlling the lifecycle is language specific (depend on reference vs value semantics).  In UML, "composition" is an informal shortcut for "composite aggregation", and indeed there is a control of lifecycle.

Comment: If Exercise is composed of ExerciseForWorkout, it basically means that if Exercise is destroyed, so are all its ExerciseForWorkout.  In the literature you'll find a lot of reference to "part-whole" relationships, but the current UML 2.5.1 does no longer use this subjective wording and just adds on the top of the lifecycle that Exercise somehow represents the whole group.  ("the instance representing the whole group is classified by the owner of the Property, and the instances representing the grouped individuals are classified by the type of the Property"), which is semantically correct in ...

Comment: ... your case.  But as you see, I did not put it as a first choice either.  I mentioned it for the case you want to underline the lifecycle control.  I prefer to avoid composite aggregation when possible and recommend to first consider the simple association.  The 1..1 (could be abbreviated in 1 by the way) is sufficient to suggest that the exercise must be there, and that of course something should happen if the exercise would disappear.  By the way, deletion would be hard, because people would use all their pas workouts.  Better not to delete and deactivate with a status. ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, you've been marvelous in the explanation.